# Renaming Tabs using Macros

Tags: excel, vba

I want to rename tabs within a workbook so that when I change figures in a certain cell in the first tab, the tab name automatically changes with it.

I don't want a button assigned for the macro (unless necessary). So far my code has not followed through.
This is my original code but the tab names don't change with it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'calls ChangeSheetName() in a regular code module to do the work
'when the contents of cell B1 on the sheet changes
  If Target.Address <> 1. & "$B$1" _
   Or Target = "" _
   Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub ' nothing to be done
  End If
 Run "ChangeSheetName" ' call the routine to do the work
End Sub
```

If anyone can help with this then that would be great!

Update: I've tried using this code below now but it still doesn't change the tab. It should be noted that the cell used for naming is in a different tab.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Address(False, False) = " '0. Overview'!$B$3" Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.Name = Target.Value
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the `1.` in `If Target.Address <> 1. & "$B$1"`?

Comment: "1." what I want to appear in the tab before the contents of the cell, for example, "1.201906"

Comment: Ok. But the cell address won't have `1.` in it. The cell address is just `$B$1`, right? Also, please share the code for `ChangeSheetName`.

Comment: Don't include the sheet name in the comparison of `Target.Address`. Just the cell reference.

Comment: ^ For a more detailed explanation of how `Range.Address` works, here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address).

Comment: Where do you define to what each sheet is renamed? Is it a fixed cell on each of the sheets? Is the cell location the same on each sheet? Why is the only trigger for change the cell on the first worksheet? If you explain to us what exactly it is you are trying to do we may be able to come of with a better solution. The questions sounds a bit like a XY-Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not much to change:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'calls ChangeSheetName() in a regular code module to do the work
    'when the contents of cell B1 on the sheet changes
    If Target.Address <> "$B$1" Or Target.Value = "" Or Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then
         Exit Sub ' nothing to be done
    End If

    Call ChangeSheetName ' call the routine to do the work

End Sub
```

But to add, what you can change to is just ensure that if the `Target.Address` is `$B$1` then run the call.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'calls ChangeSheetName() in a regular code module to do the work
    'when the contents of cell B1 on the sheet changes
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Value <> "" Then
         Call ChangeSheetName ' call the routine to do the work
    End if

End Sub
```

Comment: Or just get rid of `Call`, it's generally considered deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the name of the Worksheet to whatever is written in the Cell B1. In this case you can use this piece of code, instead of using one on each sheet.

The Typenname Check should prevent any errors if the range is not on a worksheet.

In the code-behind of ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not TypeName(Target.Parent) = "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Address = "$B$1" And Target.Value2 <> "" Then
        Target.Worksheet.Name = Target.Value2
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help, as soon as you leave the sheet4 tab, sheet1,2,3 change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Sheet1.Name = "North " & Sheet4.[E1] & " " & Sheet4.[F1]
    Sheet2.Name = "EAST SIDE " & Sheet4.[E1] & " " & Sheet4.[F1]
    Sheet3.Name = "WEST SIDE " & Sheet4.[E1] & " " & Sheet4.[F1]
End Sub
```